# pypy3.6-v7.3.1 install grpcio

Tags: pip

when i use pypy3.6-v7.3.1 to install grpcio, its has some error

```
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-std=gnu99’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
    gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -D_WIN32_WINNT=1536 -DGPR_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY_MODE=1 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H=1 -DGRPC_ENABLE_FORK_SUPPORT=1 -DPyMODINIT_FUNC=extern "C" __attribute__((visibility ("default"))) PyObject* -DGRPC_POSIX_FORK_ALLOW_PTHREAD_ATFORK=1 -Isrc/python/grpcio -Iinclude -I. -Ithird_party/abseil-cpp -Ithird_party/address_sorting/include -Ithird_party/cares -Ithird_party/cares/cares -Ithird_party/cares/config_linux -Ithird_party/re2 -Ithird_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/include -Ithird_party/upb -Isrc/core/ext/upb-generated -Isrc/core/ext/upbdefs-generated -Ithird_party/zlib -I/usr/local/pypy3.6-v7.3.1/include -c third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/ssl/tls_record.cc -o python_build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/ssl/tls_record.o -std=c++11 -std=gnu99 -fvisibility=hidden -fno-wrapv -fno-exceptions -pthread
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-std=gnu99’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
    creating None/tmp/tmpdspzk75c
    gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/pypy3.6-v7.3.1/include -c /tmp/tmpdspzk75c/a.c -o None/tmp/tmpdspzk75c/a.o
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/pypy3.6-v7.3.1/lib-python/3/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 133, in _compile
        extra_postargs)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-0n4wn2nk/grpcio/src/python/grpcio/_spawn_patch.py", line 54, in _commandfile_spawn
        _classic_spawn(self, command)
      File "/usr/local/pypy3.6-v7.3.1/lib-python/3/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
        spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
      File "/usr/local/pypy3.6-v7.3.1/lib-python/3/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
        _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
      File "/usr/local/pypy3.6-v7.3.1/lib-python/3/distutils/spawn.py", line 159, in _spawn_posix
        % (cmd, exit_status))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

its only tell me gcc failed, no more reason, can you help me ?

My container is:

- Docker Centos7.8
- PyPy 7.3.1 with GCC 9.2.0  with Python 3.6.9
- gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)

In the same docker container,
i try use pypy2.7 or python3 to install grpcio, there is no problem .

Answer (score 0):

If it suits your needs you can try using grpcio==1.26.0.
That version compiles fine on pypy3 + gcc 9.3.0, at least on my wsi ubuntu.

```
pip install grpcio==1.26.0
```